# Google photos chrome extension with fast preview

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, google-photos

I am looking for extension for Google Photos within chrome browser which will allow fast preview of the pictures (without changing the page) - similar to "SPACE" in MacOS Finder.

If there are any other tricks for this please share.

Thanks a lot in advance.